# webstorm live edit, "IDE debugging this tab" takes a while to display

Tags: webstorm, liveedit

Live Edit works eventually but I have to hack a while before the '"JetBrains IDE Support" is debugging this tab' appears. That message does not appear after I click 'Open in Browser' (with 'Live Edit' checked). The generated background page for the JetBrains Chrome extension shows the plugin and IDE are communicating properly right away.

I get around this by clicking various tags in the html file, and the 'debugging' message comes up after 30-45 secs. Live Edit works fine from this point.

Is this normal? How can I make it more responsive?
[Windows 7, latest Chrome & JB plugin, 'only' 24 Chrome tabs open.)

Answer (score 0):

workaround with ahk for winows:

```
 ;~ leider verweigert chorome irgendwie die erkennung wenns deaktiv ist. vermutlich hat an deaktives window unter chorome an anderen namen.


t :=      "php - Google Chrome ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1"
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance force
;hardBackup 

;clipboard:=""
;~ MsgBox,%A_LineNumber%


HardDriveLetter := SubStr(A_ScriptDir, 1 , 1) 
ScriptNameLetter := SubStr(A_ScriptName, 1 , 1) 
iconAdress=%HardDriveLetter%:\fre\public\Graf-Bilder\icon\abc123\%ScriptNameLetter%.ico
ifexist,%iconAdress%
    Menu, Tray, Icon, %iconAdress%
else
  ToolTip,http://www.branchenbuch-weltweit.dk/img/abc/a.png

IfWinNotExist,%t%
{
    ToolTip,%t% `n does not exist.
    MsgBox,%t% `n does not exist.
    Sleep,5000
    ExitApp
}
; aAa
SetTitleMatchMode,2
#IfWinActive,PhpStorm 7.1 ahk_class SunAwtFrame
 ~A::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~B::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~C::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~D::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~E::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~F::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~G::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~H::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~I::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~J::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~K::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~L::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~M::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~N::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~O::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~P::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~Q::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~R::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~S::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~T::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~U::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~V::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~W::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~X::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~Y::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return 

 ~Z::
    SingleKeyInput("dummy")
  return

 ~Enter::
    SingleKeyInput("activate")
  return


SingleKeyInput(m)
{
    global t
    ;~ MsgBox,ControlSend f5 %t%
    ; /develop/ConverterIni2awl/php/www/ConverterIni2awl.class.php - Google Chrome ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    if( StrLen(t)<1 )
        MsgBox, :( len(t)<1
    SetTitleMatchMode,2
    IfWinActive,PhpStorm
    {
        WinGetActiveTitle,at
        ;~ Suspend,on
        Sleep,1000
        if(m = "activate")
        {
            ; this works more often then the alternative method
            WinActivate,%t%
            WinWaitActive,%t%,,1
            IfWinActive,%t%
            {
            send,{f5}
            WinActivate,%at%
            Sleep,1100
            Reload ; sometimes reloading helps faster developing thte ahk script.
            }
        }

        IfWinNotActive,%t%
            ControlSend,,{f5},%t%
        ToolTip, f5
        Sleep,1000
        ToolTip, 
        ;~ Suspend,off
    }
    return
}
```